# nginx returning 404 not found for GET request

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have the following nginx.conf for my nginx server

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /service_data {
            root /opt;
            index service_state;
        }
    }
}

events {}
```

When I do

```
curl ip_address:80
```

nginx returns its standard output, which is OK. But when I try

```
curl ip_address:80/service_data
```

it returns the following

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

however the contents of my file /opt/service_state

```
First line
Second line
```

which is just a plain text.

I expected the following behavior:

```
curl ip_address:80/service_data
```

which returns

```
First line
Second line
```

Am I wrong with my nginx.conf? How do I get the expected behavior?

**EDIT:**

`nginx -T` prints the following

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        location /service_data {
            root /opt;
            index service_state;
        }
    }
}

events {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the nginx [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/):

> The root directive specifies the root directory that will be used to search for a file. To obtain the path of a requested file, NGINX appends the request URI to the path specified by the root directive.

So you could change the location to:

```
location /service_state {
        root /opt;
       # index service_state;
    }
```

Or change the file name:

```
service_state -> service_data
```

Comment: I've edited my config, but nginx still same result. I have nginx installed on VM, so not on my host. Could it be the reason?

Comment: Could you please run `nginx -T` to print all configs and edit the question with the complete nginx config?

Comment: I've edited my question. Seems like nginx uses exactly my config....

Comment: I changed to answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you! It works just fine